# What is the difference between messages and notifications?

Tags: winapi

Some controls have two types of (Messages, Notifications).
For example, ListBox has "notifications" like:

- LBN_SELCHANGE
- LBN_SETFOCUS

And "messages" like:

- LB_SETCURSEL
- LB_SELECTSTRING

I know each one what it does but I don't know what's the difference between them messages and notifications?

Comment: There are `WM_COMMAND` notifications, which arrive in the `HIWORD(wParam)` of `WM_COMMAND` messages. And there are `WM_NOTIFY` notifications, which arrive in the `nmhdr.code` of the `WM_NOTIFY` message. Read the documentation for each notification to see what kind it is.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thank you, But unfortunately, documentation is very broad which make me lost.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's right there [in the very first paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lbn-selchange): "The parent window of the list box receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, notifications ARE messages.  It is just a matter of who is sending a message and who is receiving it.

In your particular use-case example, a "message" is sent to the control to make it do something, and a "notification" is sent by the control to its parent window (which you can hook into to handle notifications as needed) to inform of something that happened in the control.

Comment: Thank you, as I know `messages` are similar to the events in the modern programming but what about `notifications` are similar to what?

Comment: @LionKing it is the other way around. `messages` are commands you issue, and `notifications` are events you receive.